# Angularcli headers

Tags: c#, jquery, angular, angular-cli

What is the equivalent to jquery

```
$scope.SetHeaders = function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'ValueID': ValueID
            }
        });
    };
```

What I tried so far in angular cli.

```
pushvalueId(paramid: number): Observable<any[]> {
    let myHeaders = new Headers(); 
    myHeaders.set('ValueID', '77');  
    let myParams = new URLSearchParams();
    myParams.set('ValueID', paramid.toString());
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders, params: myParams });
    return this._http.post(this._getreport, options)
}
```

What I am trying to do initially is retrieve the header value in my class.

```
 public int ValueID { get; set; }
  ValueID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("ValueID"));

`import { Http, Response, JsonpModule, HttpModule, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';`
```

Comment: is this `angular` or `angular-js`?

Comment: angular2 so angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are using deprecated http client. You should use `'@angular/common/http'`

Second argument for [post method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) is `body`. For options you have to use 3rd argument:

```
this._http.post(this._getreport, null, {headers: myHeaders, params: myParams})
```

Don't use `RequestOptions` - these are part of the old http client and [deprecated](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions)

Comment: Ok I give it a try.

Comment: ok. I made the change. take a look @Martin Nuc.`constructor(private _http2: HttpClient) { }`                                                                                            `ReportId(paramid: any): Observable<any[]> {
    let header = new  HttpHeaders;
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    header.append('ValueID', paramid);
    let myParams = new HttpParams();
    myParams.set('ValueID', '587');
    return this._http2.post(this._getreport, null, {headers: header, params: myParams})`